# Should I use Struts 1 or 2 with jQuery?

Tags: java, jquery, jakarta-ee, struts

I want to develop a Java EE application with a rich user interface which uses Ajax heavily.  I know that I can use Ajax frameworks like jQuery and Dojo to achieve this.  I have worked previously on Java EE with Struts (1.x)  and Hibernate.

But recently I found that Struts 2 has inbuilt Ajax support.  Is it worth it to use Struts 2?  I am not familiar with Struts 2.  Should I go with Struts 1 or 2?  If I use Struts 2 will I have to use jQuery also or does Struts 2 have custom tags that support Ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts 2. You will have to use jquery (not only helper tags).

Answer (score 2):

Use Struts 2, Struts 1 is extremely antiquated.  Struts 2 is considerably different from Struts 1 though, so your knowledge of Struts 1 probably won't transfer much (except for general purpose understanding of the servlet request / response life cycle, etc).  There's a [Struts 2 JQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) that you can use for Ajax.  Don't use the Dojo ajax support, it's deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Next to Struts 2, you should maybe consider JSF 2. This is a very good web framework that has great build-in support for Ajax as well.

There are lots of component libraries that are a good showoff of how AJAX can be used in JSF, e.g. see the [PrimeFaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf).

Answer (score 0):

You should use GWT. Seriosly. Struts is good, but nothing beats GWT if your goal is Ajax.

Comment: i guess gwt is very heavy, i want pages to be loaded quickly